# layer components is not working in global.css in talwind css

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[image]I get following error for `@layer components` on `global.css` in `tailwind.css` I got the same error when try importing tailwind base, componenets, and utilities and i resolved it using
@import and tilde ~. like following. guess this can solve by the same way but don't know how to write `@layer components` in that way.

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base";
@import "~tailwindcss/components";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities";

@layer components {
  .link {
    @apply cursor-pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used npm install tailwindcss

Comment: you can see my file structure on my github repo https://github.com/imangi/amazon-clone

Answer (score 0):

[As the documentation states](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), you should write:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

If that is not working for you, please share your configuration for the tailwind configuration file and we'll try to help you as best as we can :)

Comment: module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        amazon_blue: {
          light: "#232F3E",
          DEFAULT: "#131921",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  varients: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],


};

Comment: above is my tailwind config

Comment: Have you followed the documentation exactly?

Comment: yes. I followed

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, just change your code like this

[image]

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer components {
  .link {
    @apply cursor-pointer;
  }
}
```

have a nice day!